# Filtering monthly returns of a fund by its series type

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with filtering data from mutual funds. I have data from a fund but each fund has different types of series, so for example: I have 3 returns of December 2006 of series A, B and C, but I only want to have the one of series A. I want to have monthly returns from December 2006 to December 2010 but only from series A. My data is ordered like this: First column we have the dates, second column we have the series and third column the returns.
I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
FILTER(C1:C127;B1:B127="A";"None")
```

Sample data:
[image]
Hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Post few sample data so that we can see how your data looks like. Your formula structure looks fine.

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Comment: I don't want to receive none, I made a mistake. I want to have all the monthly returns in order in a column but only with series A, so I want to delete those columns that are not from series A.

Comment: Why not just use the regular or advanced filter?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you just use a normal filter? [Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcnGj.png)